# hexagons with image inside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS/HTML version of this image below, trying to make every hexagon shape a clickable element that opens a popup to describe the content of the clicked item

I used [Hexagon Generator](http://csshexagon.com/) to create my elements, but I couldn't manage to order them in the way they should be / or similar, according to this image. (Main image in the middle and hexagons around it)

And making the whole thing responsive (mobile-ready), that's another problem.

[image]

Comment: Probably to reproduce that image with css will be very difficult, I think you need to change the concept and use canvas, take a look to this library: http://fabricjs.com/ there are lots as fabric.js

Comment: do you have any working code you could put down in a snippet? i think you could still do this with just html/css. a first pass could be hammering everything into place with `absolute` positioning. *edit, though the lines connecting to the center and the pop-out do definitely look more they'd need a canvas/js solution*

Comment: Actually no, i don't have anything useful yet, i know I will need some JS for the popups, that's fine with me, i am just still stuck with what to do for the elements surrounding the image.

Comment: This can be done. The order of the hexagons are initially set using position absolute with CSS position offsets like top, right, bottom, and left. And then you can use CSS transforms to adjust the position of them (translateX and translateY) when a responsive view is triggered so they keep their general layout but in a responsive view.

Answer (score 4):

This is in no way an optimized solution, and I can probably create something much better, but I wanted you to take a look at one of the ways this can be done.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hex">
  <div class="hex-title">
    Simple title
  </div>
  <div class="hex-hide"></div>
  <div class="hex-img">
     <img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/Q7STENMU1K.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hex{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:50px auto;
  position:relative;
}
.hex:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:0;height:0;
  border:80px solid transparent;
  border-top:0px solid #fff;
  border-left:145px solid #fff;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:9999;
}
.hex:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:0;height:0;
  border:80px solid transparent;
  border-top:0px solid #fff;
  border-right:145px solid #fff;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:9999;
}
.hex-title{
  width:105%;
  height:40px;
  background:#005A87;
  position:absolute;
  margin:auto;
  left:-2.5%;top:0;bottom:0;
  z-index:99999999999;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:2px;
}
.hex-img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.hex-img img{
  max-height:100%;
}
.hex-hide{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
}
.hex-hide:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:0;height:0;
  border:80px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:0px solid #fff;
  border-left:145px solid #fff;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:9999;
}
.hex-hide:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:0;height:0;
  border:80px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:0px solid #fff;
  border-right:145px solid #fff;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j74padnq/

And this is a demo that resembles the image that was posted, albeit with less details: https://jsfiddle.net/j74padnq/1/

Comment: thank you for the nice work, I have already created nice single hexagons, but my main problem was in ordering them in a way that they appear in the image above, or something similar I don't mind, I just need to explain the drug contents in a nice way :(

Comment: @tinyCoder Let me know if you want me to add something to it! Created this around 4am before i went to bed, so i didn't give it much thought, but i'd be more than happy to help. The bounty is very tempting lol

Comment: Man, what you did was awesome!! as a single hexagon it looks very great, but I am still trying to create multiple hexagons around the drug image, got what I mean?

Comment: Ah, i see. Well, that's pretty easy. Let me organize them and update my answer

Comment: Thanks man, what you did is awesome, however I have 12 hexagons around the drug image, not just 6! which actually I don't know how to deal with, you deserve the bounty! and I will appreciate if you help implementing the 12 shapes, best regards!